# Animation does not work for animation-iteration-count :1(or any number other than infinite)

Tags: css, css-animations

animation-iteration-count:infinite works perfectly fine but when I change the count to a number the animation stops working completely.

Please check the code below any help would be great.

HTML:

```
<div  class="guidDisplay slideIn"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.guidDisplay {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: slideIn ease-in 1;
  animation: slideIn ease-in 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 750ms;
  animation-duration: 750ms;
}

.slideIn {
  -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

When I change the animation from `bounce 2s infinite)` 
to `bounce 2s 1`, animation stops working also if I include
animation-iteration-count:1., it does not work.

Comment: Where is the keyframe code for your bounce animation? Add that to the question. Also, if your problem is not with Sass then always post the compiled CSS because not all users would know Sass.

Comment: Voting to close as "cannot be reproduced" because there is not enough information to reproduce the problem.